# Install dotnet core tool Dockerfile

Tags: docker, .net-core

I have an .net core application where I would like to make a SonarBuild inside a container.

So I have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build as build-env

WORKDIR /src

COPY question-metrics-api/question-metrics-api.csproj question-metrics-api/
COPY question-metrics-data/question-metrics-data.csproj question-metrics-data/
COPY question-metrics-domain/question-metrics-domain.csproj question-metrics-domain/
COPY tests/question-metrics-domain-tests/question-metrics-domain-tests.csproj tests/question-metrics-domain-tests/

RUN dotnet restore tests/question-metrics-domain-tests
RUN dotnet restore question-metrics-api/question-metrics-api.csproj

COPY . .

#Run tests
RUN dotnet test tests/question-metrics-domain-tests/question-metrics-domain-tests.csproj

#Begin Sonar
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner
RUN dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"question-metrics-api" /d:sonar.host.url="http://sonarqube:9000" /d:sonar.login="7ed84e09a17a31e783fa8522d876e27fe4624977"
RUN dotnet build
RUN dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="7ed84e09a17a31e783fa8522d876e27fe4624977"
#End Sonar

RUN dotnet publish question-metrics-api/question-metrics-api.csproj -c Release -o publish

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore as runtime-env

COPY --from=build-env src/question-metrics-api/publish .
EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "question-metrics-api.dll" ]
```

When I try to build this dockerfile I got an error:

```
Step 11/19 : RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner
 ---> Running in 78719975f3b0
No executable found matching command "dotnet-tool"
```

How can I install dotnet tool from aspnetcore-build image?

#### Update

Ok, If I use the base image microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk I don't get anymore `No executable found matching command "dotnet-tool"` error, now I get `No executable found matching command "dotnet-sonarscanner"`

How can I use sonarscanner tool in this scenario?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

As I have read in this thread: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/issues/520, we can run a dotnet tool global command inside a container setting the following line:

`ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.dotnet/tools"`

So my final Dockerfile is like:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk as build-env

WORKDIR /src

COPY question-metrics-api/question-metrics-api.csproj question-metrics-api/
COPY question-metrics-data/question-metrics-data.csproj question-metrics-data/
COPY question-metrics-domain/question-metrics-domain.csproj question-metrics-domain/
COPY tests/question-metrics-domain-tests/question-metrics-domain-tests.csproj tests/question-metrics-domain-tests/

RUN dotnet restore tests/question-metrics-domain-tests
RUN dotnet restore question-metrics-api/question-metrics-api.csproj

COPY . .

#Run tests
RUN dotnet test tests/question-metrics-domain-tests/question-metrics-domain-tests.csproj

#Begin Sonar
RUN dotnet tool install -g dotnet-sonarscanner

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.dotnet/tools"

RUN dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"question-metrics-api" /d:sonar.host.url="http://sonarqube:9000" /d:sonar.login="7ed84e09a17a31e783fa8522d876e27fe4624977"
RUN dotnet build
RUN dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="7ed84e09a17a31e783fa8522d876e27fe4624977"
```

Hope that helps someone!

Comment: The path of dotnet tools is a bit diffrent: `$HOME/.dotnet/tools`
Therefore use: `ENV PATH="${PATH}:/${HOME}/.dotnet/tools"`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools#install-a-global-tool

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build as build-env
```

That's the issue. Look at the dockerhub page for this: https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/aspnetcore-build/. See how it says that it only supports versions 1.1 and 2.0:

> Latest images for 2.1 and newer are now available on microsoft/dotnet. See this link for more details about migrating to 2.1.

`dotnet tool` is only available in 2.1 and later. That's why doing `RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner` fails. `dotnet` doesn't know about a `dotnet tool` command at all. It tries to look for `dotnet-tool` in your $PATH, as a fallback, but no such thing exists either.

You actual fix was:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk as build-env
```

Because this uses the new 2.1 SDK, which does know of the `dotnet tool` command.

Comment: Actually, when I just changed the base image I did install dotnet core tool, but couldn't use it. Just install and don't be able to use solve half my problem, maybe I should change the title of the question to "Use dotnet tool in container" to reflect better my problem