# Why dotnet command is not found in dockerfile?

Tags: shell, docker, .net-core, dockerfile, docker-build

I tried to run a dotnet command located in a shell file which will be called by dockerfile during the docker build process.

Here is the dockerfile snippet:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk as build-env

# .net core 
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y wget apt-transport-https
RUN wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb && dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-2.2=2.2.1-1

# dotnet tool command
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.2 -y
# for dot net tool #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977474/install-dotnet-core-tool-dockerfile
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.dotnet/tools"

# Supervisor
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y supervisor && mkdir -p /etc/supervisor

# main script as defacult command when docker container runs
# Run the main sh script to run script in each xxx/*/db-migrate.sh. 
CMD ["/xxx/main-migrate.sh"]

# Microservice files
ADD xxx /xxx

# install the xxx deploy tool
WORKDIR /xxx
RUN for d in /xxx/*/ ; do cd "$d"; if [ -f "./install.sh" ]; then sh ./install.sh; fi; done
```

In the `install.sh`, here is the code:

```
dotnet tool install -g xxx.DEPLOY --version [$(cat version)] --add-source /xxx/
```

When I run `docker build -t xxx:v0 .`, I get an error message saying:

> ./install.sh: 1: ./install.sh: ﻿dotnet: not found

I have added `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk as build-env` & `RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.2 -y`, but why Docker could not find the dotnet command during build?

How do I call the `dotnet` command located in the shell script file during the docker build process?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk as build-env
```

In the above lines `FROM ubuntu:16.04` will be totally ignored as there should be only one **base image**, so the last `FROM` will be [considered as a **base image**](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) which is `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk` not the ubuntu.

So if your base image is `FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk as build-env` then why to bother to run these complex script to install **dotnet**?

You are good to go to check version of dotnet.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk as build-env
RUN dotnet --version
```

output

```
Step 1/6 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk as build-env
 ---> f13ac9d68148
Step 2/6 : RUN dotnet --version
 ---> Running in f1d34507c7f2

> 2.2.402

Removing intermediate container f1d34507c7f2
 ---> 7fde8596c331
```

Comment: Your answer helped me to realize the reason why `dotnet` command could not be found. The wrong `FROM` part of my docker file caused it. Then I fixed it by changing it from `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS build-env` to `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build-env`. Thank you.