# How to use dotnet tools inside a container?

Tags: docker, vscode-remote, sonarscanner

I'm experimenting Visual Studio Code Remote.
I want to use [SonarScanner](https://sonarcloud.io/documentation/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/) for code quality analysis. I've followed the guides and installed the tool on host but when I try to use it from the container, I get:

```
# dotnet sonarscanner -h                                    
No executable found matching command "dotnet-sonarscanner"
```

On host:

```
$ dotnet sonarscanner -h
SonarScanner for MSBuild 4.7.1
Using the .NET Core version of the Scanner for MSBuild

Usage: 

  SonarScanner.MSBuild [begin|end] /key:project_key [/name:project_name] [/version:project_version] [/d:sonar.key=value] [/s:settings_file]

    When executing the begin phase, at least the project key must be defined.
    Other properties can dynamically be defined with '/d:'. For example, '/d:sonar.verbose=true'.
    A settings file can be used to define properties. If no settings file path is given, the file SonarQube.Analysis.xml in the installation directory will be used.
    Only the token should be passed during the end phase, if it was used during the begin phase.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this post can help you!

[Install dotnet core tool Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51977474/install-dotnet-core-tool-dockerfile)

we can run a dotnet tool global command inside a container setting the following line:

```
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.dotnet/tools"
```

> Dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk as build-env

WORKDIR /src

COPY question-metrics-api/question-metrics-api.csproj question-metrics-api/
COPY question-metrics-data/question-metrics-data.csproj question-metrics-data/
COPY question-metrics-domain/question-metrics-domain.csproj question-metrics-domain/
COPY tests/question-metrics-domain-tests/question-metrics-domain-tests.csproj tests/question-metrics-domain-tests/

RUN dotnet restore tests/question-metrics-domain-tests
RUN dotnet restore question-metrics-api/question-metrics-api.csproj

COPY . .

#Run tests
RUN dotnet test tests/question-metrics-domain-tests/question-metrics-domain-tests.csproj

#Begin Sonar
RUN dotnet tool install -g dotnet-sonarscanner

ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.dotnet/tools"

RUN dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"question-metrics-api" /d:sonar.host.url="http://sonarqube:9000" /d:sonar.login="7ed84e09a17a31e783fa8522d876e27fe4624977"
RUN dotnet build
RUN dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="7ed84e09a17a31e783fa8522d876e27fe4624977"
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be before the installation of the scanner? Does the scanner works without of JAVA installed?

Answer (score 2):

Got It! [I've found an article explaining it](https://andrewlock.net/running-net-core-global-tools-in-non-sdk-docker-images/).

It was just including this instructions on Dockerfile.

```
ENV SONNARSCANNER_VERSION 2.3.38
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner --version $SONNARSCANNER_VERSION
ENV PATH="/root/.dotnet/tools:${PATH}"
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet-sonarscanner"]
```